# Why when I enter this powershell code its not executed?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I tried to remove all tags with specific value but my code its not executed

```
$tagname = "tagname"
$TagValue ="tagvalue"
get-AzureRmResource -TagName $tagname -TagValue $TagValue | Remove-AzureRmTag
```

What i need to do to end/execute this code ?

Comment: When I press Enter on last line of code it transfers me to the next line instead of delete all tags... Please help !

Comment: Take a look at this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154432/how-to-delete-tags-from-multiple-azure-services) and you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to remove the pair of `tagname:tagvalue` in all resources which have it, try the command below, it should work.

```
$Tagname = "tagname"
$TagValue ="tagvalue"

$Resource = Get-AzureRmResource -TagName $Tagname -TagValue $TagValue
$Resource | ForEach-Object { $_.Tags.Remove($tagname) }
$Resource | Set-AzureRmResource -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because Remove-AzureRmTag expects to receive a tag to delete, but you are passing it a resource (the output of get-AzureRmResource is a resource).

I'm not overly clear on what you are trying to achieve, are you trying to remove all instances of a specific tag, with a specific value, from any resource? If that is the case then this isn't the right command to use anyway, as it will only delete the tag if it is not in use.

Comment: Yeah , I want to remove instances of a specific tag, with a specific value, from any resources. Thanks for your help

Comment: The sample joy provided should work fine for what you want